# Servlet/Tomcat relative file path

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

**Where to put files in a Tomcat Servlet application, such that they are relatively visible to the page??**

More detail:
I am developing a **servlet** page while using an **external library**. That library depends massively on external **loaded XML files** (relative file paths). So I need to put these XML files in the **running directory** of the servlet.

Is there a way in Tomcat server, where files can be accessible **relatively**?

Comment: You can use `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to get the current working directory. Print it and you know where to put your files...

Comment: From there, you can access the whole file structure.  Great comment Moritz.

Comment: Yep, I have done simillar idea, I have written to a file in that directory, but it turns out to be a temporarily directory that tomcat creates...

Comment: So I was asking if there a way to tell tomcat to copy certain files to this directory as well

Comment: Could be interesting to mention which library you are talking about.

Answer (score 3):

When a web application is deployed to Tomcat, the root of the web application ends up being $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/YOUR_WEB_APP/

As such, if using a servlet to access an XML file located on a path within the root of your web application, you can just use the following:

```
request.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("PATH/TO/YOUR/XML_FILE.xml")
```

This will load the XML file as an `InputStream`. Of course, if you want access to the file itself, you can always use the `getResource(String resource)` method to obtain a `URL`, from which a `File` object can be obtained like so (alternative methods included):

```
File f;
try {
  f = new File(url.toURI());
} catch(URISyntaxException e) {
  f = new File(url.getPath());
}
```

EDIT: To make them relatively visible to a web browser, simply keep them out of the ./WEB-INF and ./META-INF directories.

Comment: Put I have no access to the code of the external library... I only know that it loads the files with relative paths..

Comment: I guess I'm confused then. What are you trying to do? Just make the XML files accessible to the external library? If so, your relative path is the application root.

Answer (score 1):

If this library you are talking about is going to search for the file on the classpath (like Hibernate or Log4J would do), you will have to put your XML file in WEB-INF. However, I suggest you do not do this manually. You can put the file in a source directory of you application, which will make sure the file gets deployed on the right spot.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old question. I'm working on Tomcat 9. I've been quite successful with taking the Tomcat installation directory as the base. (CATALINA_HOME) The relative path to a file in ROOT for example is then, "webapps/ROOT/someDir/fileName"

The place to complain about repeated answers is to deal with repeated questions.

Comment: This assumption is only valid with the default Tomcat configuration. If somebody's set an explicit `docBase` (see [context container documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html)) the webapp could be anywhere.

Comment: But I suspect if that was the case, he'd know what docBase he'd set.